# Definitions of a homotopy

Tags: homotopy-theory

Why are the following two definitions for a homotopy equivalent?

> Let $f,g: X \to Y$ be maps. Then $f \simeq g$ if and only if there is a map $G:X \to Y^{I}$ such that $G(x)(0) = f(x)$ and $G(x)(1) = g(x),$ for all $x \in X$.

and

> Suppose maps $f,g:X \to Y$ are maps. We say that $f$ is homotopic to $g$, written $f \simeq g$, if there is a continuous function $F: X \times I \to Y$ such that $$F(x,0), \quad F(x,1) = g(x), \quad \text{and} \quad F(*,t) = *.$$

In the first definition there is no mention of a base point as opposed to the second definition so I am wondering how that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

$Y^I$ is the space of continuous functions from $I$ to $Y$.  The topology on it is the natural topology, which is the finest topology for which for every continuous function $H : X\times I \to Y$ there exists a continuous function $\hat{H} : X \to Y^I$ such that $H(x,t) = \hat{H}(x)(t)$.  We make it into a pointed space, by defining the point $*_{Y^I} = t \mapsto *_Y$.  So for any continuous function $F : X\times I \to Y$ we have a continuous function $\hat{F} : X \to Y^I$, but $\hat{F}$ will only be base point preserving only if $F(*_X,t) = *_Y$ as that means $\hat{F}(*_X) = (t \mapsto *_Y) = *_{Y^I}$.  No requirement is made for $F(x,t)$ when $x \neq *_X$.  If the first definition only required $G$ to be a continuous function then these definitions would not be equivalent.

However, to go the other way we need to be able to make a continuous function $G' : X\times I \to Y$ given a continuous function $G : X \to Y^I$ such that $G'(x,t)=G(x)(t)$.  Here the fact that $I$, the unit interval $[0,1]$, is compact Hausdorff means that it is locally compact which means that such a function always exists.  This also makes the natural topology on $Y^I$ the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).  In other words, all this rambling about "natural topologies" and "locally compact", just means that we are assured that the function $H(x) = t \mapsto H'(x,t)$ is always continuous and that we can always find such a continuous function $H'$, namely $H'(x,t) = H(x)(t)$.  It's obvious that we can do this as plain functions, but it is not obvious that they will be continuous.

Comment: What if $G$ is not base point preserving?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the meaning of "map" is intended, in this case, to be "base point preserving continuous function".  If $f$ ($g$) is a base point preserving map, then $G$ will be if $0$ ($1$) is chosen as the base point for $I$. If none of $f$, $g$, or $G$ are base point preserving, then these definitions aren't equivalent, and the base points are just randomly floating around doing nothing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the beginning of the book we assumed functions to be based, and I think map here means the same as function. But how does that mean that $G$ is base point preserving?

Comment: You are correct, I did make a mistake in the comment. $G$ isn't necessarily base point preserving under the conditions I gave in the comment.  Instead, the condition of the first block quote make $G$ base point preserving *by definition*.  There may be non-base point preserving continuous functions (i.e. non-maps) that otherwise satisfy the conditions.  Those would not be homotopies.

Comment: So for $G(x,t)$ such that $x \in I$ we have that $G(x,t) = *$? Is that what they mean by $G: X \to Y^{I}$?

Comment: $Y^I$ is the space of continuous functions from $I$ to $Y$ with the natural topology, which, since $I$ is compact, is the [compact-open topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology).  We make it into a pointed space by adding the point $*_{Y^I} = t \mapsto *_Y$.  So $G(*_X) = t \mapsto *_Y$, i.e. $G(*_X)(t) = *_Y$.  Nothing is said about $G(x)(t)$ when $x \neq *_X$.

Comment: My book says "We regard $Y^{I}$ as a based space with base point the constant path $*$ which takes all of $I$ to the base point of $Y$." So by all of $I$ does it mean $\forall x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: Yes, where what you call $x$ here is the parameter $t$ in the second definition and my answer.  $I$ is the interval $[0,1]$.  I made some edits to the answer to incorporate some of the comments.

Comment: Does that mean that $G(x,t) = *$ for all $x \in I$?

Comment: No. $G$ is a function that returns a function, so it's $G(x)(t)$, not $G(x,t)$. Next, $X$ may have nothing to do with $I$, so $G(x)(t)$ may not even be defined for $x \in I$.  Even if it is, unless $x = *_X$, there is no constraint.  What it does mean is that $G(*_X)(t) = *_Y$ for all $t \in I$.